# Difference between Stencil -structures and Cellular Automata Category-theoretically?

Tags: computability, terminology, ct.category-theory, machine-models, cellular-automata

> **Definitions**
>
> **Stencil** =
>   *"For a given point, a stencil is a pre-determined set of nearest
>   neighbors (possibly including itself)."*
>   [(source)](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~kdatta/pubs/mspc06_slides.pdf)
>
> **Wikipedia's definition ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_codes)) =**
>   [image]

It looks like CA (cellular automata) is a broader (and perhaps more sexy fuzzy populist) concept while the stencil (S) is more rigorous. Suppose a torus -topology in a grid and a simple structure where each state depends only on the next state (some transition rule, 4 neighbors but only next state matters). This I think is a Stencil, Cellular automaton, a grid, a mesh, easily described with Markov Chain -- and a structure. Now I am confused! So many different words for the same thing? Please, add references to quantify this concept, many authors seem to use different words for the same thing -- not sure what it is, some structure with function -definitions -- perhaps there exists some easy category-theoretic description for them?

If this is too elementary question, I would be happy about some reference covering definitions rigorously and doing some comparisons.

**Perhaps related**

2. Automatic Stencil Code Generation Ph.D. Thesis Proposal [here](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~kdatta/talks/quals_proposal_07.pdf). The author behind the last paper [here](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~kdatta/), researching something about stencil things and a lot of perhaps related publications [here](https://ftg.lbl.gov/staff/swwilliams/), related to the last author.
3. Fey, Dietmar et al. (2010) Grid-Computing: Eine Basistechnologie für Computational Science. Page 439. ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_codes#cite_note-Fey-2))
4. Complex Systems from the Perspective of Category
   Theory: I. Functioning of the Adjunction Concept [here](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/1236/1/Axiomath.pdf)

Comment: You will find that these are different (but related) concepts defined in different communities and used for different (and possibly unrelated) reasons. I suspect that you need to read more in detail about each of these concepts and understand them in their original setting, in isolation of other settings. Trying to find a description in terms of category theory will probably make things less easy to  understand, unless you are very good with categories.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the source you provided, there appear to be two key differences:
(1) stencils have numeric values in each cell and update the cells with functions defined numerically (typically using continuous functions) while cellular automata typically have only a finite set of values per cell and use functions that in general do not arise from numerical methods, and (2) stencils are updated by a sweep across the grid while in cellular automata generally all cells are updated simultaneously.

Comment: Could you clarify `"stencils are updated by a sweep across the grid"`? What is a `"sweep"`?

Comment: A sweep is a monotone traversal.

Comment: @RickyDemer: what is a `"monotone traversal"`? Monotonic function that traverse over the grid?

Comment: Does this mean that the updating with stencil is not necessarily simultaneous? Is the word `"sweep"` meant here as a desciptive word (like a sweeping a table with finger) or does it have some rigorous definition?

Comment: I just mean looping over the array elements one at a time in the sort of order you would get from a standard nested for-loop structure.

Answer (score 2):

There does indeed exist a category theoretic description of cellular automata. I don't know the details, but I can provide you with a reference. It doesn't look like an *easy* description, though.

S. Capobianco, T. Uustalu. [A categorical outlook on cellular automata.](http://cs.ioc.ee/~tarmo/papers/jac10.pdf)
In J. Kari, ed., Proc. of 2nd Symp. on Cellular Automata, JAC 2010 (Turku, Dec. 2010), v. 13 of TUCS Lecture Notes, pp. 88-99. Turku Centre for Computer Science, 2010.

Comment: They use uniform spaces! I've been looking for an application of them to PL for some time now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.